# How to separate text to words without to copy comma or any other punctuation?

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm using the next code to separate text to words and then inserting those words into database.
The problem is that comma is also copied.
How can I skip from comma to copied or any other punctuation?

```
var str = reader1.ReadToEnd();
string[] words = str.Split(' ');   //Insert all the song words into words named string
string constring1 = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=abc";

using (var conDataBase1 = new MySqlConnection(constring1))
{
    conDataBase1.Open();
    for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
      {
          int numberOfLetters = words[i].ToCharArray().Length; //Calculate the numbers of letters in each word  
          var songtext = "insert into myproject.words (word_text,word_length) values('" + words[i] + "','" + numberOfLetters + "');"; //Insert words list and length into words table
          MySqlCommand cmdDataBase1 = new MySqlCommand(songtext, conDataBase1);
          try
            { 
              cmdDataBase1.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
              {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);  
              }
       }

 }
```

Comment: Use Regex.  See webpage : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing your Split line with this:

```
 char [] separators = new char[] {' ', ',', '/'};
 var words = str.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToArray();
```

You'll get punctuation free words. You can add to the `separators` array other punctuation you want stripped out. I put in space, comma, and `/`.

Comment: You're welcome. It's customary on Stack Overflow to accept (by clicking the green checkbox) an answer to your question that helps you.

Comment: Which green checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

`str.split("[\\p{Punct}\\s]+")` will split the string from punctuation and white spaces.